# Dependency property inside viewmodel in Prism

Tags: mvvm, prism, dependency-properties

Is there any way to declare dependency property inside viewmodel? I want to declare a dependency property inside viewmodel and change it's value through command.

```
public class MyViewModel : Prism.Windows.Mvvm.ViewModelBase
    {
        public bool IsPaneVisible
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsPaneVisibleProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsPaneVisibleProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsPaneVisibleProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("IsPaneVisible", typeof(bool), typeof(MyViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(0));

        public ICommand VisibilityChangeCommand { get; set; }

        public MyViewModel()
        {
            VisibilityChangeCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnVisibilityChange);
        }

        private void OnVisibilityChange()
        {
            IsPaneVisible = !IsPaneVisible;
        }
    }
```

Problem is, I am getting some compilation error in IsPaneVisible' getter/setter : "GetValue does not exist in the current context". Is there any alternative way to do this?

Comment: Why does it have to be a dependency property? A regular property should be enough in the view model.

Comment: I have two Visual States and I wanted to toggle between those states based on a Dependency property value with a Data trigger behaviour. I thought to use Invoke command action which will change the value of the dependency property, and thus will toggle between states

Answer (score 3):

A `DependencyProperty` is used on a [`DependencyObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject(v=vs.110).aspx), an example of this is a `UserControl`. Prism's ViewModelBase is no `DependencyObject`, mainly because this type is platform specific. To support binding from a viewmodel, we typically use `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Prism implements this interface in the [`BindableBase`](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Prism/Mvvm/BindableBase.cs) base class, from which ViewModelBase derives as well. You define your properties like this:

```
private string _imagePath;
public string ImagePath
{
    get { return _imagePath; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _imagePath, value); }
}
```

If you install the [Prism Template Pack](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e7b6bde2-ba59-43dd-9d14-58409940ffa0) Visual Studio extension, you can use the `propp` code snippet.